# Can you help me with this definition of a set that is presented?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I do not understand all of this mumbo jumbo. Ok here is the set: $\{{x} : x ∈ A\}$ What is this set when set $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$. Set $A$ is a completely arbitrary set that I came up with. I am more concerned about the definition $x ∈ A$ mumbo jumbo. Can you also comment on cardinality if it is relevant. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "mumbo jumbo"?

Comment: $\{x: x\in A\} = A.$

Comment: This is what I mean by mumbo jumbo $x:x ∈ A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(x)$ is a statement about $x$, then in general $\{x \: : \: p(x)\}$ should be read as
$$\text{"The set consisting of elements $x$, such that the statement $p(x)$ is True."}$$

Thus $\{x \: : \: x \in A\}$ should be read as
$$\text{"The set consisting of elements $x$, such that $x$ is an element of $A$".}$$
It follows quite trivially that $\{x \: : \: x \in A\} = A$.